# How to use math fonts correctly in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, context, lua

I am using the ConTeXt engine in Texlive 2023 to typeset my article.
When I use the XITS Math font, apparently the superscripts of the summation symbols are misaligned, similar to that
When I use the STIX Math font, apparently the superscripts of the integral symbols are misaligned, is this something that needs to be set somewhere, can someone help me

```
\definefontfamily [myfonts] [rm] [texgyrepagella]
\definefontfamily [myfonts] [ss] [texgyreadventor]
\definefontfamily [myfonts] [tt] [texgyrecursor]
\definefontfamily [myfonts] [mm] [XITS Math] % not right for sum  symbol
%\definefontfamily [myfonts] [mm] [STIX Math] % not right for int  symbol
\setupbodyfont[myfonts, 14pt]
\starttext
1. $\displaystyle \int_L (x^2-y) d x-(x+\sin^2y) d y$

2. $\displaystyle \iint\nolimits_D \frac{\sin x}{x} d x d y$

3. $\displaystyle \iiint\nolimits_{\Omega}(x^2+y^2) d v$,

4. $\displaystyle  f(a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z - a} dz$

5. $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^n}$.
\stoptext
```

```
\definefontfamily [myfonts] [rm] [texgyrepagella]
\definefontfamily [myfonts] [ss] [texgyreadventor]
\definefontfamily [myfonts] [tt] [texgyrecursor]
\definefontfamily [myfonts] [mm] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math] % works better
%\definefontfamily [myfonts] [mm] [XITS Math] % not right for sum  symbol
%\definefontfamily [myfonts] [mm] [STIX Math] % not right for int  symbol
\setupbodyfont[myfonts, 14pt]
\setupmathematics[differentiald=upright]
\starttext
1. \dm{\int_L (x^2-y) \dd x-(x+\sin^2y) \dd y }

2. \dm{ \iint_D \frac{\sin x}{x} \dd x \dd y}

3. \dm{ \iiint_{\Omega}(x^2+y^2) \dd v}

4. \dm{  f(a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z - a} \dd z}

5. \dm{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^n} }
\stoptext
```

Comment: I am away from computer. But at some point I think we gave up the support on these fonts. Stixtwo works better. If you still want to set up these fonts, you will need to set up a goodie file (see *-math.lfg for examples).

Comment: Also, `\dm{ }` could replace `$\displaystyle $`. And `\limits` and `\nolimits` are not meant to be used in context.

Comment: (Instead you can set up operators with `\setupmathoperator`, with the `method` key.). One additional comment: In context you  can use `\dd` to get a differential d,. That will improve the spacing around your dx, dy and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your enthusiastic help,  I am a newbie  to ConTEXt.

Comment: One more thing: if you use pagella for text, maybe the best option is to also use pagella math for the math.

Comment: I don't know much about the matching of body font and mathematical symbol font in ConTeXt. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: In ConTeXt we can use \dd to get a differential d as you said,but how do we get the upright differential sign in ConTeXt?

Comment: Try `\setupmathematics[differentiald=upright]`.

Comment: @mickep I finally found something I like of ConTeXt!  The differential d is in italics by default! 

Comment: @egreg Oh, I'm still looking for a clean differential d in LaTeX, italic or not. 

Comment: I use the following statement to get the upright differential sign in LaTex

`\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\! \mathrm{d}}`